# How to solve the recursive complexity T(n)= T(n/4) + t(3n/4)+1?

Tags: runtime

How do i solve the recursive complexity

T(n)= T(n/4) + t(3n/4)+1 ?

I have already tried solving the problem using iteration method.

The answer should be O(n).

Comment: This might be on-topic in http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion tree method or [Akra–Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method). Using Akra–Bazzi method:

```
g(n) = 1 
a1 = 1
a2 = 1  
b1 = 1/4
b2 = 3/4
```

Now, find the value of `p` for which (1/2)<sup>p</sup> + (3/4)<sup>p</sup> = 1 . `p` will come out `1`. Using formula

[image]

you will get the value for integration part equal to 1 - 1/x. Finally you will get the value of entire expression is `2x - 1`. Its big theta notation is equivalent to big theta notation of `x`.